# iOSPlot: How to display multiple charts on the same view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am developing an iPhone app which requires charts. Hence I am using API called iOSPlot to draw line charts.

I have downloaded API from this link

https://github.com/honcheng/iOSPlot

Graph appears fine.

I want to display one graph below the other on the same view.

How can I do that?

I suppose it is printing out the charts on UIView and as per my requirement the charts could be more than 1.

So how can I display more than one chart on the same view?

Comment: You can try to use a `UIScrollView`

Comment: @j_freyre: Thanks for the input but I think this wont be useful as I may have 10 UIView or even 1 UIView. Plus all this is programmatically created and also it needs to plot different data for different charts. Also problem with ScrollView is that I cant capture a screenshot for the whole contentsize of the scrollview. I need to send the whole image through Email and also allow it to print out to any connected printers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working?

```
PCHalfPieChart *pieChart1 = [[PCHalfPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:pieChart1];
// adding dataset1 to pieChart1

PCHalfPieChart *pieChart2 = [[PCHalfPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 10, 50, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:pieChart2];
// adding dataset2 to pieChart2
```

Or this way:

```
PCLineChartView * lineChart;

// you should find a way to define your x, y, width and height correctly.
// I have not enough information about your project to find a solution
// I admit that there is 4 var called x, y, width and height

for (int i=0; i < numberOfChart; i++) {
    lineChart = [[PCLineChartView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    // Add some data
    // it can be based on the index to define which data goes to which chart
    // ...

    [self.view addSubview: lineChart];
    [lineChart release];

    // Changing values of x, y, width and height
    // should come here
}
```

Comment: I am drawing a line chart not a pie chart. Also I have to generate them programmatically so cannot name them as you have given as I cannot predict how many charts would be there. Also requirement is that it needs to be fullsize where in as you said above in your answer it would divide the screen and hence graphs would be scaled to smaller size.What can be done in that case?

Comment: Thanks for the input. but what about the screen capture? I cannot capture the whole image and also as I previously mentioned I cannot just keep addsubviews to the visible part of the view as it may vary from 1 to any number.